# How do you move through a 2D array without for loops?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I am trying to build a treasure hunt game using test files I have been given. These texts files are of chars S,W,E,N and T which all correspond to directions except for T, which is the treasure. Everything works fine until it moves the length of the rows/columns. I suspect it has something to do with the for loops but I'm not certain. **Is there a way to do this without for loops or does anyone have any advice to get this back on track?**

Here is my **Updated** code so far:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class NewGridGame {
    public static final int FALL_OFF = -1;
    public static final int GOING_IN_CIRCLES = -2;
    private int row;
    private int col;
    private char[][] gameBoard;

    NewGridGame(int conRow, int conCol, char[][] conGameBoard) {
        row = conRow;
        col = conCol;
        gameBoard = new char[row][col];
        for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gameBoard[i].length; j++) {
                gameBoard[i][j] = conGameBoard[i][j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(gameBoard));
    }

    public int playGame() {
        boolean[][] beenHereBefore = new boolean[row][col];
        int turns = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while (true) {
            if (beenHereBefore[i][j] == true) {
                return GOING_IN_CIRCLES;
            } else {
                beenHereBefore[i][j] = true;
            }
            if (gameBoard[i][j] == 'N') {
                if (i - 1 >= 0) {
                    i--;
                    turns++;
                    System.out.println(turns);
                    System.out.println(gameBoard[i][j]);
                } else {
                    return FALL_OFF;
                }
            } else if (gameBoard[i][j] == 'S') {
                if (i + 1 < row) {
                    i++;
                    turns++;
                    System.out.println(turns);
                    System.out.println(gameBoard[i][j]);
                } else {
                    return FALL_OFF;
                }
            } else if (gameBoard[i][j] == 'E') {
                if (j + 1 < col) {
                    j++;
                    turns++;
                    System.out.println(turns);
                    System.out.println(gameBoard[i][j]);
                } else {
                    return FALL_OFF;
                }
            } else if (gameBoard[i][j] == 'W') {
                if (j - 1 >= 0) {
                    j--;
                    turns++;
                    System.out.println(turns);
                    System.out.println(gameBoard[i][j]);
                } else {
                    return FALL_OFF;
                }
            } else if (gameBoard[i][j] == 'T') {
                return turns;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of a test file as well.

```
ES
TW
```

this one should return 3, which is the number of moves (turns, in my code) but instead it gets to W (which takes 2 moves) and returns -2, which is only for when it's gone to a position more than once. Additionally, not all of the Arrays are squares, some are 1x200 or 4x5 for examples.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better served by seeing how to do this *properly using* for loops?

Comment: I suppose you're right, as you are suggesting that there indeed is a way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the board is such that, starting at (0, 0), you won't get stuck in a loop or move off the board you can just used something like this:

```
public int playGame()
{
  int numMoves = 0; 
  int currentRow = 0;
  int currentCol = 0;

  while(gameBoard[currentRow][currentCol] != 'T')
  {
    switch (gameBoard[currentRow][currentCol])
    {
    case 'E': currentCol++; break;
    case 'W': currentCol--; break;
    case 'S': currentRow--; break;
    case 'N': currentRow++; break;
    default:
       throw new IllegalStateException("Unrecognized Move");
    }
    numMoves++;             
  }

  return numMoves;
}
```

You may want to use `if-then-else` instead of a `switch`.

If you need to check for loops or off-board moves you should be able to add these checks in.

Comment: Hi there! I've edited to just a while loop with if-then-else statements as I am more familiar with them.. However I still am not getting a return statement that I should be for the test file I included in my initial question. It is still catching after the 2nd move as if it's been to that place before which it hasn't.. would you have any ideas as to why that is?

Comment: I see in your original code that you're updating the values on the board. You don't really need to do this - just change the (row,col) of your current position. Also, do you really need to track where you've been, or is there a guarantee that boards will always terminate at T? Do you want to update your question with your current code?

Comment: Updated. There is no guarantee that they will always end at T as the game will end/return if it 'falls off the board' or goes to a position it's already been to before ie. tries to move north in a row position 0 or moves E and then moves W right after. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I found the issue. It was a silly problem with my test file, It wasn't calling the right class. The code above works :) Thank you for your help!